# Assign Virtual Public IP in ESXi lab environment

Tags: firewall, vmware-esxi, ip, virtual-machines

I'm working on creating a lab environmenton VMware ESXi 6.0 for firewalls VMs and networking features. so one of our steps is to simulate the firewall like in real environment.
So I have at least 2 virtual interfaces for the firewall one for wan and for lan . But what i nerd to simulate is that like in real world tou get real public ip address to access internet.
but in my case i will assign on virtual WAN interface i will assgin random public ip like : 207.365.35.124/29
but i need to nat this random public ip to local ip of the host
so it can access the internet through the local of the host (ESXi) server.
[Please click on the link to see the image to clarify the point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPA7q.jpg)
in other words : I know how to traditional nat local ip to public ip to access the internet , but what I need to do is the opposite which is nat public ip assigned to virtual interface and nat it to local ip of the uplink of the phsyical NIC of THE ESXi.
Maybe i need to use internal VM as a router or something.

Any suggestions.

Comment: So you're saying the public IP is currently assigned to the ESXi host itself? Do you have other IP addresses available?

Comment: Thanks for the comment , but this not the case i'm talking about . I have attached an image in the original question .so please feel free to have a look.